# How to share a big byte array between C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pointers, arrays

I need to share a huge (many megabytes) byte array between a C++ program residing in a DLL and a C# program.

I need realtime performance, so it is very important I can share it between the two in an efficient way, so making a new copy for it in C# every time after the data is manipulated in C++ is not an option, yet the examples I have found so far seems to depend on this.

Is it possible to share the array in an efficient way? And if so, how?

Comment: Tell me about your threading model.  Does access to that array need to be safe, in the concurrent sense?

Comment: I have a question: Is the C++ assembly added as a reference to your C# project? Or are you using interop services to access it?

Answer (score 4):

In current versions of .NET, any multi-megabyte array will end up on the large object heap and never move.  However, to be safe, you should pin the array as fejesjoco said.  Then the C++ code can save a pointer into the .NET array and update it in-place.

Comment: I'd be careful here.  If it ends up less that 16kb, it can and will get placed in the LFH.  Just something to be aware of.

Comment: .NET doesn't use the OS heap, low fragmentation or otherwise.  It does its own memory management.  And pinning will work for arrays of all sizes, even if they end up on the generational heap instead of the LOH.

Answer (score 2):

Use memory mapped file. `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles` in .NET and CreateFileMapping in C++.

Comment: If the C++ code were a separate program rather than a DLL, this would be best.  For sharing memory with a DLL it's overcomplicated.

Comment: ...and it's only available starting with .NET 4

Answer (score 1):

Does the .NET marshaler pass a copy, not a reference? If so, then call GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned), then you can get the address of this pinned object and pass that to the DLL as a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In vb.net, I've accomplished this by passing a reference to the first byte.  There's no type-checking to ensure that what's passed is really an array of the proper size, but as long as the routine is running the array will be pinned.